# How do I set the order of execution of my already existing subjobs in Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have many subjobs in a single job in Talend and I want to be able to pick the order in which they should sequentially execute. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you'll have to link all subjobs, using onSubjobOK trigger links. If subjobs are not linked, you can't select the order of subjob executions : it will probably execute the first subjobs you created first (depending on the order on the java code generated).

When you have linked all subjobs, you can modify link orders just by right-clicking on a 'OnSubJobOK' link (select 'modify link order), and reorganize all links in the popup).